# Catch block in axios is not working when deployed to heroku but it works perfectly fine when I run the code locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have made a login functionality. It is working fine when I run it locally, but after I deployed to Heroku I am getting H12 error. However, I am getting H12 error **only** when I insert incorrect email or password but I am able to login when both password and email-id are correct. Here below is my code:

app.js

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const viewRouter=require('./routes/viewRoutes');
const userRouter=require('./routes/userRoutes');
const globalErrorHandler=require('./controller/errorController')
const path=require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const compression=require('compression');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const xss=require('xss-clean');
const mongoSantize=require('express-mongo-sanitize')
const helmet=require('helmet')
const csp=require('express-csp')
//app.use(compression())
app.use(express.json({limit:'10kb'}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dev-data')))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.use(xss())
app.use(mongoSantize());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'http:', 'data:', 'ws:'],
      baseUri: ["'self'"],
      fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'http:', 'data:'],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'", 'https:', 'http:', 'blob:'],
      styleSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'https:', 'http:'],
    },
  })
);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  next()
})
app.set('view engine','pug');
app.set('views','./views');
app.set('trust proxy',1)

app.use('/',viewRouter)
app.use('/api/v1/user',userRouter)

app.use(globalErrorHandler)
module.exports=app;
```

userRoutes.js

```
const express=require('express');
const userController=require('./../controller/userController')
const authController=require('./../controller/authController')
const router=express.Router();
router
  .route('/login')
  .post(authController.login)
```

authController.js

```
const {promisify}=require('util')
const catchAsync = require("./../utils/catchAsync");
const AppError=require('./../utils/appError')
const User=require('./../models/user_model')
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken')
const Email=require('./../utils/email')
const crypto=require('crypto');


const signToken=(id)=>{
  let token=jwt.sign({id:id},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn:'90d'})
  return token
}
const createSendToken=(user,statusCode,req,res)=>{
  let token=signToken(user._id)
  let cookieOptions={
    expires:new Date(Date.now()+90*24*60*60*1000),
    httpOnly:true
    }
  user.password=undefined
  res.cookie('jwt',token,cookieOptions)
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status:'success',
    data:{
      user
    },
    token:token
  })
}
exports.login=catchAsync(async(req,res,next)=>{
  
  //1) check if email and password exist in req.body
  if(!req.body.email||!req.body.password){
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password', 400))
  }
  //2) check if user exists in DB and password is correct
  let user= await User.findOne({email:req.body.email}).select('+password')
  
  if(!user){
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email-id or password',400))
  }
  let correct=await user.comparePassword(req.body.password,user.password)

  if(correct==false){
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email-id or password',404))
  }

if(user.active==false){
    return next(new AppError('Please verify you email id',404))
  }
  //3) If everything is okay, send token to the client
  createSendToken(user,200,req,res)
})
```

appError.js

```
class AppError extends Error{
  constructor(message,statusCode){
    super(message)
    this.statusCode=statusCode;
    this.isOperational=true;
    if(`${this.statusCode}`.startsWith(4)){
      this.status='error'
    }
    else{
      this.status='fail'
    }
    Error.captureStackTrace(this,this.constructor);
  }
}
module.exports=AppError;
```

catchAsync.js

```
module.exports=fn=>{
  return (req,res,next)=>{
    fn(req,res,next).catch(err=>{next(err)})
  }
}
```

login.js

```
import {notification} from './notification_display.js'
let login_btn=document.querySelector('.login_btn');
let reset_password_btn=document.querySelector('.reset_password_btn');
let sign_up_btn=document.querySelector('.sign_up_btn');
let lost_login_link_btn=document.querySelector('.lost_login_link_btn')
let notify=document.querySelector('.notify');
if(reset_password_btn){
  reset_password_btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    window.open('/forgotPassword',"_self")
  })
}
if(sign_up_btn){
  sign_up_btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    window.open('/signUp',"_self")
  })
}

if(lost_login_link_btn){
  lost_login_link_btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    window.open('/lostSignUpCode',"_self")
  })
}

const login=async(obj)=>{
  let res
  try{
    res=await axios({
      method:'POST',
      url:'/api/v1/user/login',
      data:obj
    })
    if(res.data.status=='success'){
      console.log({message:'Your are logged in!'})
      notification('You are logged in')
    }
    console.log(res.data)
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err.response)
    notify.classList.add('error')
    console.log(err.response.data.message)
    notification(err.response.data.message)
  }
}

login_btn.addEventListener('click',async(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  let email=document.getElementById('email').value
  let password=document.getElementById('password').value
  let login_obj={}
  login_obj.email=email;
  login_obj.password=password;
  console.log('Keep on pushing...you might make it')
  console.log(login_obj)
  await login(login_obj)
  //console.log("ooops i dont its working")

})
```

error.response.data.message is logged as "undefined"

following is the error.response.data that I get logged on the client side when incorect email-id/password or when both of them is not provided :

```
{data: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n\t<html>\n\t  <head>\n\t\t<meta name=\"vi…ication-error.html\"></iframe>\n\t  </body>\n\t</html>", status: 503, statusText: "Service Unavailable", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "/api/v1/user/login", method: "post", data: "{\"email\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n\t<html>\n\t  <head>\n\t\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n\t\t<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\t\t<title>Application Error</title>\n\t\t<style media=\"screen\">\n\t\t  html,body,iframe {\n\t\t\tmargin: 0;\n\t\t\tpadding: 0;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t  html,body {\n\t\t\theight: 100%;\n\t\t\toverflow: hidden;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t  iframe {\n\t\t\twidth: 100%;\n\t\t\theight: 100%;\n\t\t\tborder: 0;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t</style>\n\t  </head>\n\t  <body>\n\t\t<iframe src=\"//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html\"></iframe>\n\t  </body>\n\t</html>"
headers:
cache-control: "no-cache, no-store"
connection: "keep-alive"
content-length: "506"
content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
date: "Sun, 13 Jun 2021 15:36:35 GMT"
server: "Cowboy"
__proto__: Object
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 503
statusText: "Service Unavailable"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What happens when you provide an empty username and password? Also, when you provide a bad username/password - do you see the errors logged in console (on the client side)?

Comment: @MattOestreich I have edited the question, you can see the error that gets logged on the client side in both the cases. I cannot really understand why the error.response.data.message comes out to be undefined when the app is deployed to heroku. However it works really fine when correct email-id and password are provided.